# Angularjs replace pdf content in HTML embed tag

Tags: angularjs, pdf, embed

I have the following HTML button that fires a to load a pdf content with a byte array:

The following is the HTML embed tag to display the PDF content:

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
    <embed ng-src="{{content}}" style="width:700px;height:800px;" id="pdf" />
</div>
```

The following is the AngularJS code which update the "content" when the button is clicked:

```
$scope.changeContent = function(bytes) {
    var file = new Blob([bytes], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    console.log("fileURL is "+ fileURL);
    $scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
}
```

The PDF file displays only on the first invocation of the "changeContent()" call.  On the subsequent calls the HTML embed file is not being loaded with other newer PDF file's bytes.  Is there something I am missing to reload the embed content with new pdf content?

thanks
-Sonam

On the first click of the button, the content is loaded v

Comment: adding the HTML button tag here that I missed after the first sentence:           <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="changeContent(x.bytes)">

Comment: updating have to be did editing your own post and not in comments.

Comment: Do you have any plunker/fiddle for this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a clue what that is.  So no.  I just have a webapp on my local machine.  To gp_sflover,  I couldn't find a edit button, I am new here.    I will edit it if I can find it.